# What would the wavefunction represent in an observer-less universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability, quantum-measurements

Suppose the universe has no observers, and the universe's dynamics is governed by the Schrodinger equation. What does the wavefunction represent now? Is it that parts of the universe keep measuring other parts of the universe and the wavefunction represents the statistical description of what measurements get recorded as the universe evolves?

Answer (score 2):

You probably misunderstood what "observer" means. It has nothing to do with people, consciousness or anything of the sort.

In quantum mechanics, an observation, or a measurement, is an interaction with a very large system that leaves the object entangled with the larger system.

The mechanism isn't completely understood, at least we know that the traditional "collapse of the wavefunction" fits reality correctly so far.

Back to your question, a universe without observer in the quantum sense of the word would be devoid of any large system, which would probably imply some other changes in the laws of physics to *prevent* larger systems from forming over time. An empty universe, perhaps?

Comment: Let's say only Earth gets destroyed. The other large systems continue to exist. Does this mean that parts of the universe keep measuring other parts and recording results in accordance to the wavefunction's absolute squared value?

Comment: Also, does the wavefunction have no meaning in a universe of only small systems?

Comment: What is your definition of "recording"? In any case, Earth is nothing special, so its presence or absence has no bearing on physics. If you're in a universe where large bodies can form, then measurement is possible. Don'( forget that gravitational interactions are enough to trigger decoherence (maybe not quickly).

Comment: Does the wavefunction have no meaning in a universe of just two electrons as the initial condition? Wikipedia says decoherence doesn't explain collapse.

Comment: And Wikipedia is right, I never said that decoherence is collapse. However, decoherence is a necessary first step before "collapse" (or whatever phenomena hide behind this word). You have to choose a basis before you can choose which eigenstate to collapse to.